# How do I query more than one column in a data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I'm taking a Data Science class that uses Python and this is a questions that stumped me today. "How many babies are named “Oliver” in the state of Utah for all years?"
To answer this question we were supposed to use data from this set https://raw.githubusercontent.com/byuidatascience/data4names/master/data-raw/names_year/names_year.csv

So I started by loading in pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
```

Then I loaded in the data set and created a data frame

```
url='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/byuidatascience/data4names/master/data-raw/names_year/names_year.csv'

names=pd.read_csv(url)
```

Finally I used the .query() method to single out the data type that I wanted, the name Oliver.

```
oliver=names.query("name == 'Oliver'")
```

I eventually found the total number of babies that had been named Oliver in Utah using this code

```
total=pd.DataFrame.sum(quiz)

print(total)
```

but I wasn't sure how to single out the data for both the name and the state, or if that is even possible. Is there anyone out there that knows of a better way to find this answer?

Comment: What is `quiz` and what's your expected output?

Comment: If quiz stands for state, then I assume that you are looking for something like: total = pd.DataFrame.sum(names.query("name == 'Oliver'")['UT'])

Comment: Similar but a bit different: `total = names.query("name == 'Oliver'")["UT"].sum()`

Answer (score 0):

You have all the code there you just need one more line to Sum accordint to the state:

```
print(oliver.UT.sum()) # this will give you the total for the state of UTAH
```

and forget about the quiz.